# unveil and lazy load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an index page for a website where I have a lot of images in a masonry gallery. Right now its loading a bit slow and I am trying to use lazyload and unveil. Originally, I tried lazyload, but I need to maintain a width proportion so I opted instead for **unveil.js**

However, after trying to implement unveil, I find my images do not load at all. Here is a sample of my markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="Peter Lum Fluid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="Snap.svg-0.1.0/dist/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</style>   
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src-"jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')  </script>
<title>Peter Lum</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="jquery.unveil.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").unveil();
 });

$(function(){
    $("img").unveil();
});



$("img").unveil(200, function() {
$(this).load(function() {
this.style.opacity = 1;
});
});

</script>



<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div id="LayoutDiv1"><!--Use Insert Panel for additional Fluid Grid Layout Div tags. Note: All Layout Div tags must be inserted directly inside the "gridContainer" div tag. Nested Layout Div tags are not currently supported.-->
<header>
    <a class="logo" href="mailto:hello@peterlum.co"></a>


    <h1> Peter Lum </h1>

 <hr>
        <ul class=" navigation scaling">
             <li class="scaling"><a href="about.html"><img class="invert" src="images/about.png"></a></li>
             <li class="scaling"><a href="index.html"><img class="invert" src="images/work.png"></a></li>
             <li class="scaling"><a href="contact.html"><img class="invert" src="images/contact.png"></a></li>
             <li class="scaling"><a href="http://www.peterlum.co/blog"><img class="invert" src="images/blog.png"></a></li>
             <li class="scaling"><a data-pin-do="buttonFollow" href="http://www.pinterest.com/peterlunglum/pins/"><img class="invert" src="images/pinterest nav.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>


</header>
</div>

<div id="LayoutDiv2" class="container">

     <div class="box">
         <div class="article">
            <img alt="Atelier" class= "thumbnail img lazy" src="images/blank.png" data-src="images/Atelier-2.png"><h4>A Shop of Work</h4>
              <p> <a class="" href="#">Read more »</a></p>
         </div>
     </div>

</div> 
<!-- /container -->

<div id="backtotop"></div>



  <div class="footer">
     `enter code here`  <p> Work of Peter Lum. Thanks for visiting. Website designed myself using Masonry. ©2014.</p>
  </div>

 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
        $('#backtotop').fadeIn();   
    } else {
        $('#backtotop').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('#backtotop').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},900);
  });   
 });
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I included just one image div so far. Can anybody tell me why it doesn't load my images in layoutdiv2? The documentation of unveil says that the usage of unveil has syntax like this:

```
 <img src="bg.png" data-src="img1.jpg"/>
```

Do I have to follow that exact syntax for it to work? Moreover, is that simply the problem or is something else wrong?

Comment: first thing.. put all your js before </body> in one place, and your jquery should be the first line there.

Comment: Did you notice that you have 3 jQuery versions included in your HTML?

Comment: My suggestion: remove all the unnecessary code, format everything, put all the javascript at the bottom of the page including all the files and scripts in correct order. Then double check your img tags, since, as far as I can see from your website, you HTML is not the same as you post it here.

Comment: I made the changes, but still to no avail. For unveil to work, does a class have to be made in my CSS? For lazy loading, there is a class of lazy which I left in my above for no reason, but for unveil it does not seem like there is a need for any classes. As it is, the input for data-src is not getting the image and is leaving the space blank.

Comment: Is requirement the pure jQuery? Because if is not then I recommend to you Bootstrap and https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery

Answer (score 2):

First on your css you have to write

```css
img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
}
```

then you can run plugin

```js
$("img").unveil(200, function() {
  $(this).load(function() {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unveil/1.3.0/jquery.unveil.min.js"></script>
```

But because this plugin is jQuery dependencies, you can change `this.style.opacity = 1;` with `$(this).css( { 'opacity': 1} );`

Now on your `<img>` tag, you can use custom attribute like `data-src="img2.jpg" data-src-retina="img2-retina.jpg"`